# ASPX: Redirect, remove QueryString but don't create history in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, browser-history

I'm looking for a way to get rid of the querystring of a page and redirect to itself but preserver the querystring data in some way.
Example: `http://www.test.de/somepage.aspx?id=abc` should redirect to `http://www.test.de/somepage.aspx`. Still, after the redirect, I want to be able to pick up the parameters that were originally passed. And I don't want to have `http://www.test.de/somepage.aspx?id=abc` in the browser's history.

What I tried so far:

- `Response.Redirect()`: does a proper redirect without creating browser history but I cannot preserver the parameters.
- `Server.Transfer`: preserves the parameters but the browser's URL remains unchanged.
- Create a client form on the fly and submit in `onload`: works, querystring is gone, parameters are accessible through Request.Form, but creates a history entry in the browser.

The only thing I can currently think of is to store the parameters in the session, then redirect, then pick them up from there. But maybe there's still another solution?

Comment: Sounds like you have the best answer already - store the qs in session and perform a `Response.Redirect(url);`. Is there a reason you don't want to use session?

Comment: The main reason is the complexity of handling it. You might have two browser tabs open showing the same page and they share one session. There's a great chance that one will overwrite the other if the processing times differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pete mentioned, you can save your querystring parameters in Session and then call to Response.Redirect to redirect to the second page

```
Session["id"] = Request["id"];
Session["param2"] = Request["param2"];
Session["param3"] = Request["param3"];
....
Response.Redirect(sameurl);
```

In the second load of the page check if the querystring values are gone. If they are, instead of reading values from querystring read the values from session.

```
id = Session["id"];
param2 = Session["param2"];
param3 = Session["param3"];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into why you want to do this, your best bet is storing the parameters in the session state. Session state should be used minimally though as it leads to unreliable applications. E.g. what happens if your user stores a bookmark, or hits Refresh after the session has timed out? For these reasons, I'd advise against this approach.

You could consider employing URL rewriting to make the parameters you need look more friendly, for example like this: http://www.test.de/somepage/abc

Comment: Yeah, I know that...but my problem is the standard AJAX issue. You go to "http://www.test.de/somepage/abc" or "http://www.test.de?somepage=abc" and then use XHR to go show content of another page you'll end up with:
"http://www.test.de/somepage/abc#somepage=def" or "http://www.test.de?somepage=abc#somepage=def".

That's what I want to avoid. Stil I want allow users to directly go to a page using the URL querystring syntax they are used to.

René